# Estimating probability of a score (Pig) C++

Tags: c++, probability

(I'm using C++, sorry!)

I need to simulate a single turn of a game of Pig. The user defines a "hold" value, and a dice is rolled until that value is met/passed, or until a 1 is rolled, which sets the score to 0 and ends the turn.

There is another value, turnNum, if you will, that will decide how many times this turn will be simulated with that holdNum.

Where I'm running into a wall is that it needs to output the score of each attempt, as well its estimated probability, with the probability adding up to 1.000000 (100%).

For example: If the hold value was 21, and the number of times we ran the turn simulation was 4, the results may look like:

Score/Estimated Probability:

0/.500000

21/.250000

22/.250000

23/.000000

24/.000000

25/.000000

26/.000000

Which would mean our simulation hit 0 twice, 21 once, and 22 once.

I have most of the code I need already (the singleturn function, the function that simulates the dice), I just have no idea how to make it "remember" every time it got a specific score so that it can be incremented so I can then divide the number of turn simulations by that number for the probability.

Not necessarily asking for the code to be written for me, just a poke in the right direction. I can post the other functions if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language this answer could vary. But I'll assume you're using c++ or java or a similar language that has the needed types.

**Option A**

Generally in this case I would use a dynamic array to store all of the scores, then you can easily go through that array and tally what you need to at the end.

To make it super easy you could use a standard sort routine and sort the array according to size, then you can very easily get the number of each of those values.

**Option B**

Another solution would be to use a map or dictionary type which maps a particular value with another value, in this case it would map your score with a count that you would increment each time you get that score.

Something like this (c++)

```
map<int,int> myMap; //creating the std::map
myMap[thescore]++; //incrementing the score variable
```

You have tons of different options!

Comment: Totally forgot to mention it's c++ sorry. Assume arrays haven't been learned at this point. Do I make a variable for each possible score (which is 0, the hold number, up to the hold number +5) and then increment each time one of those scores occurs?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could, but that's a lot of typing you don't necessarily have to do! If you haven't had an opportunity to learn about arrays perhaps now is a good time. I believe in you!

Comment: Yes! You got it. You didn't even need the question. :-p

Comment: That's the best kind of question- the kind that you find the answer to simply by asking it! Perhaps that's one of the reasons sites like this one are so useful.

Comment: @wizebin Thanks for the help! And yeah I could go ahead and learn arrays but I'm actually helping a friend, and obviously they have to work within the constraints of what they've learned in class (don't worry I'm not just giving answers).